# Get Password In Client

Tags: c#, wcf

I send UserName & Password(Login Form) Form Client in the proxy to the server by this coding

```
myProxy.ClientCredentials.UserName="UserName";
myProxy.ClientCredentials.Pasword="Password";
```

In addition Our ClientCredentialType Must be MessageCredentialType.UserName.

in the server I need UserName & Password For Impersonate User to Make Log in the SQLSERVER with the same User that send Request to Server.
So For this I need to get Sending Password in the Server And I don't Know How Must I do it?
for get UserName I Use this Code  `ServiceSecurityContex.Current.PrimeryIdentity.Name`

Answer (score 0):

The password authenticates the user to the proxy; the proxy won't pass this information on. You'd need to explicitly pass the password to the service via the proxy to have this information available.

Comment: no no - he's really sending the credentials to the service - from his WCF client **proxy** - that's the proxy he's talking about - not a proxy along the way from his client to the service.